# Android webview youtube iframe does not go fullscreen on share button click

Tags: java, android, youtube, android-webview

I cannot provide images of my app page due to company reasons.

This is the xml of a button and webview.

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:id="@+id/stop"
    android:onClick="stop"
    android:text="Stop"/>


<WebView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/stop"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
```

And this is the java code

```
String ahtml = "<iframe class=\"col\" src=https://www.youtube.com/embed/"+videoArray[1]+" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";
youtubeWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
youtubeWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
youtubeWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
youtubeWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

This code is working fine.

Problem is that after clicking the share button,"in the youtube embed video",the height of the webview increases "downwards".

It does not go fullscreen as the button is not in the webview(which itself is not set to fill parent or full screen in the xml).

I want this button to hide and the webview to go fullscreen when the share button is clicked.

Thanks everyone for their time.